# How to call an async function inside on startup and display a specific screen based on its result?

Tags: flutter, dart

Im new to flutter and am confused on how to approach this issue.
I am trying to do the following: When the app launches check if a value exists in the DB (i have a function that gets this value for me). If it does exist then show one screen, and if it doesnt exist then show another screen.

However, ive been trying for the past hour or more and tried many things with future builder etc but cant get anything to work properly without errors. The error i currently get is: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`. I understand this might be because i didnt await it. However how can i do this because await doesnt work in the build method?

Below is the code i have currently:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  
  getUserData() async {
    final _userData = await DBProvider.db.getUserData();

    if (_userData.isEmpty) {
      print("list is empty");
      return false;
    }
    return _userData[0]['branch'];
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (getUserData == false){
      return StorePage();
    }

    return HomePage();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the value of `_userData[0]['branch'];` ? 2) This line seems incorrect `if (getUserData == false){`

Comment: @MidhunMP it will be a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: DBProvider.db.getUserData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) throw snapshot.error;
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        var userData = snapshot.data;
        return userData.isEmpty ? StorePage() : HomePage();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When a value now exists in the database, i get an error: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: @ravexu At which line?

Comment: At the return FutureBuilder line `The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#f9e86):`

Comment: You probably have an error in StorePage or HomePage. We can't tell more without source code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were right. It was something i had left in the other page. Thanks very much for your answer. I appreciate it. I was confused that future builder could not be used in this way.